# jQuery slide in menu not working on drupal

Tags: jquery, css, drupal

I am trying to create a slide in menu in a dev page I'm toying with and I am having problems running my jQuery script (the site is using Drupal 7 and jQuery 1.9.1).

PS. Explanation on the classes and id's: 
1) .toggle-nav is the class of the anchor tag that will activate the slide-in animation of the menu on click
2) #site-wrapper contains the in-canvas elements of the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.toggle-nav').click(function() {

    if ($('#site-wrapper').hasClass('show-nav')) {

    $('#site-wrapper').removeClass('show-nav');
    }   
    else {
    $('#site-wrapper').addClass('show-nav');
    }
});
});
```

The script was created with the help of this article: http://scotch.io/tutorials/off-canvas-menus-with-css3-transitions-and-transforms#browser-support-help

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Are you using Jquery update module? Try with Jquery 1.5. If that does not work, try to use next version. i.e. 1.6, 1.7 etc

Comment: Hi there! Yes i'm using the jQuery update module. Just tried your solution from jQuery 1.5 to 1.10. Doesn't seem to be working unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use a correct way of writing JS in Drupal:

```
(function($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.toggleNav = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {

      $('.toggle-nav').click(function() {
        if ($('#site-wrapper').hasClass('show-nav')) {
          $('#site-wrapper').removeClass('show-nav');
        }
        else {
          $('#site-wrapper').addClass('show-nav');
        }
      });

    }
  };

}(jQuery));
```

If this will not help, the problem is definitely somewhere outside of this script.

Comment: Hi Cornel, I have to say I am extemely grateful for your help..it finally works! Thank you so much for your time!